# Error ( No implicits found for parameter responseSerializer: MessageSerializer[Seq[SearchFormData], _] )

Tags: scala, akka, playback, lagom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU6JU.jpg)

Getting error in scala rest API while passing Seq[] in response. And when I remove Seq it works fine.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to check 1) if you have your own proper formatters for objects you have in your sequence. 2) And to check if you have play(or spray, or whatever you use to marshall and unmarshall) imported in your controller

maybe you need something like this on your controller layer

```
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpplayjson.PlayJsonSupport._
```